# C#, Create a dictionary with a stored proc then view in dgv

Tags: c#, dictionary, datagridview

I am attempting to create a dictionary from a stored procedure returning 2 columns and then show in a datagridview. This is a simplification of my end goal but currently I have:

```
List<SqlParameter> sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>();//

DataTable dt = DAL.ExecStoredProcedure("spMsgSearch", sqlParams);//run dal , get a dt back

Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();//create new dict

foreach (DataRow dr1 in dt.Rows)//for each row in the datatable add //a row from the entries within
{
     string key = dr1[0].ToString() + "-" + dr1[0].ToString();
     string value = dr1[0].ToString() + "-" + dr1[0].ToString();
     if (!dic.ContainsKey(key))
     {
          dic.Add(key, value);
     }

}//end foreach

dataGridView1.DataSource = dic;
```

Any response appreciated

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: You don't want to show the dictionary in DGV, just datatable.  You may want to sort the DataTable by field 0 using followng :  dt = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>(0)).CopyToDataTable();

Answer (score 0):

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List sqlParams = new List();//

```
        DataTable dt = DAL.ExecStoredProcedure("spMsgSearch", sqlParams);//run dal , get a dt back

        //DataSet dr = DalDataSet.ExecStoredProc("spMsgSearch", sqlParams);

        Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();//create new dict

        foreach (DataRow dr1 in dt.Rows)//for each row in the datatable add a row from the entries within
        {
            string key = dr1[0].ToString() + "-" + dr1[0].ToString();
            string value = dr1[0].ToString() + "-" + dr1[0].ToString();
            if (!dic.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                dic.Add(key, value);
            }

        }//end foreach

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dic.ToList();//the ToList solved the error
```